# Calculating a new column in spark df based on another spark df without an explicit join column

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the `df1` and `df2` without a common crossover column. Now I need to add a new column in `df1` from `df2` if a condition based on columns `df2` is met. I will try to explain myself better with an example:

`df1`:

```
+--------+----------+
|label   |    raw   |
+--------+----------+
|0.0     |-1.1088619|
|0.0     |-1.3188809|
|0.0     |-1.3051535|
+--------+----------+
```

`df2`:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+
|    probs           |    minRaw|    maxRaw|
+--------------------+----------+----------+
|                 0.1|-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
|                 0.2|-1.6195257|-1.7195256|
|                 0.3|-1.7195257|-1.8195256|
|                 0.4|-1.8195257|-1.9188809|
```

The expected output will be a new column in `df1` that get the `df2.probs` if `df1.raw` value is between `df2.minRaw` and `df2.maxRaw` .

My first aproach has been try to explode the range `minRaw` and `maxRaw`, and then joined dataframes, but those columns are continuous. The second idea is an `udf`like this:

```
def get_probabilities(raw):
    df= isotonic_prob_table.filter((F.col("min_raw")>=raw)& \
                                    (F.col("max_raw")<=raw))\
                           .select("probs")
    df.show()
    #return df.select("probabilidad_bin").value()
    #return df.first()["probabilidad_bin"]
```

But it takes a long time in my large dataframe, and give me this  alerts:

```
23/02/13 22:02:20 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
23/02/13 22:02:20 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
[Stage 82:>                 (0 + 1) / 1][Stage 83:====>            (4 + 3) / 15]23/02/13 22:04:36 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
23/02/13 22:04:36 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
```

If value is'n't between `minRaw` and `maxRaw`, the output expected is `null` and `df1` can have duplicates.

I have spark version 2.4.7 and I'm not a pyspark expert. Thank you in advance for read!

Comment: what is the expected output for rows in df1 where the `df1.raw` value isn't between any of the `minRaw` and `maxRaw` rows in `df2`?

Comment: Hi Derek, if value is'n't bet ween ´´minRaw´ and ´maxRaw´, the output expected is null.

Comment: oh i see – that will change my answer then. are there any duplicate `label + raw` values in `df1`?

Comment: Yes, df1 can have duplicates. I will be update the question with this info. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for taking the time to update your question – that's always appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just join those dataframes with the condition `between`.

```
df1.join(df2, f.col('raw').between(f.col('maxRaw'), f.col('minRaw')), 'left').show(truncate=False)

+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|label|raw  |probs|minRaw    |maxRaw    |
+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|0.0  |-1.1 |null |null      |null      |
|0.0  |-1.1 |null |null      |null      |
|0.0  |-1.32|0.1  |-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
|0.0  |-1.32|0.1  |-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
|0.0  |-1.73|0.3  |-1.7195257|-1.8195256|
|0.0  |-1.88|0.4  |-1.8195257|-1.9188809|
+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could join with a condition – this is definitely the best answer

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a [crossjoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html) between `df1` and `df2`, and apply a filter so that you're only selecting rows where `df1.raw` is between `df2.minRaw` and `df2.maxRaw` – this should be more performant than a `udf`.

Note: Since `df1` can have duplicates, we want to deduplicate df1 before crossjoining with `df2` so that after we apply the filter we don't have any duplicate rows, but still have the minimum information we need. Then we can right join on `df1` to ensure we have all of the original rows in df1.

I've also modified your df1 slightly to include duplicates for the purpose of demonstrating the result:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (0.0,-1.10),
        (0.0,-1.10),
        (0.0,-1.32),
        (0.0,-1.32),
        (0.0,-1.73),
        (0.0,-1.88)
    ],
    ['label','raw']
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (0.1, -1.3195256, -1.6195256),
        (0.2, -1.6195257, -1.7195256),
        (0.3, -1.7195257, -1.8195256),
        (0.4, -1.8195257, -1.9188809)
    ],
    ['probs','minRaw','maxRaw']
)
```

This is the result when you `crossjoin` df1 and df2 and remove duplicates:

```
df1.drop_duplicates().crossJoin(df2).show()

+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|label|  raw|probs|    minRaw|    maxRaw|
+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|  0.0| -1.1|  0.1|-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
|  0.0|-1.32|  0.1|-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
|  0.0|-1.73|  0.1|-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
|  0.0|-1.88|  0.1|-1.3195256|-1.6195256|
...
|  0.0| -1.1|  0.4|-1.8195257|-1.9188809|
|  0.0|-1.32|  0.4|-1.8195257|-1.9188809|
|  0.0|-1.73|  0.4|-1.8195257|-1.9188809|
|  0.0|-1.88|  0.4|-1.8195257|-1.9188809|
+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
```

Then we can apply the filter and right join with `df1` to make sure all of the original rows exist:

```
df1.crossJoin(df2).filter(
    (F.col('raw') > F.col('maxRaw')) & (F.col('raw') < F.col('minRaw'))
).select(
    'label','raw','probs'
).join(
    df1, on=['label','raw'], how='right'
)

+-----+-----+-----+
|label|  raw|probs|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  0.0| -1.1| null|
|  0.0| -1.1| null|
|  0.0|-1.32|  0.1|
|  0.0|-1.32|  0.1|
|  0.0|-1.73|  0.3|
|  0.0|-1.88|  0.4|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use range between in a sql expression

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')

df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')

%sql
SELECT minRaw,maxRaw,raw
FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.raw BETWEEN df2.minRaw and df2.maxRaw
```